# Numerical methods for a family of non-linear differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods

Which methods can I use to solve non-linear differential equations like this one? $$y^k+\frac{\partial^l y}{\partial x^l} = f(x), k,l \in \mathbb Z$$

Numerical methods are also welcome!

Comment: What does $l\in \mathbb{Z}$ (e.g. $l=-1$) mean? It is very unlikely that you will be able to solve such a nonautonomous nonlinear ODE with analytical methods. You should at least restrict the function $f(x)$ to be of any special type.

Comment: It was probably intended to be $\mathbb Z^+$, but I suppose we can interpret it as 1 integration each time $l$ lowers by one, so $l=-1$ would mean $\frac{\partial ^{-1}y}{\partial x^{-1}} = \int_{-\infty}^xy(t)dt$